# Two ajax calls and only one is running

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following http variable which returns an object:

```
var http = (function(){

    var success = null;
    var error = null;
    var requestInfo = {content: '', status: 0};

    var core = {
        request: function(options){
            var $http = Object.create(http);
            sendRequest(options).then(function(){
                if(typeof(success) == 'function'){
                    success(requestInfo.content);
                }
            }, function(){
                if(typeof(error) == 'function'){
                    error(requestInfo.content);
                }
            });
            return $http;
        },
        success: function(callback){
            success = callback;
            return this;
        },
        error: function(callback){
            error = callback;
            return this;
        }
    };

    function sendRequest(options){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var method = options.method.toUpperCase();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xhttp.readyState == 4){
                    requestInfo.content = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText) || xhttp.responseText;
                    requestInfo.status = xhttp.status;
                }
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    resolve(requestInfo);
                }else if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status != 200){
                    reject(requestInfo);
                }else if(xhttp.status >= 400){
                    reject(requestInfo);
                }
            };
            xhttp.open((method || 'GET'), options.url, true);
            var data = options.data || '';
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'));
            if((typeof(data) == 'object' && (Object.keys(data).length > 0) || data.length > 0)){
                xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
            }else{
                xhttp.send();
            }
        });
    }

    return core;
})();
```

If I call it more than once simultaneously, like so:

```
http.request({url: '/path1'}).success(function(){
    alert('success');
});
http.request({url: '/path2'}).success(function(){
    alert('success');
});
```

only one of the items gets passed via ajax the other one does not. What is causing this? I thought that doing `Object.create(this)` would make each one unique from each other but it doesn't seem to be doing that...

Comment: Your code works as-is, problem must be within `// The ajax stuff` https://jsfiddle.net/swqndc09/

Comment: `Object.create(this)` only creates an new object with the original `core` in its prototype chain. Therefore, any attempt to access a undefined member of the `$this` object will then search its prototype `this` and use its members if defined. Assuming you're looking to have success and error callbacks unique peer request, answer soon to come... (Mobile app is not great for code examples l

Comment: `var success = null;
    var error = null;
    var requestInfo = {content: '', status: 0};` there's your problem. just store it on $this.

Comment: wouldn't it be that sendRequest is running on the current object and not the newly created one?

Comment: Here's a fiddle we can work from: https://jsfiddle.net/swqndc09/2/ now, both of your requests complete, but the data for the second is being sent to the callback for first, and the callback for second isn't getting any data. so there's definitely a reference problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with this line:

```
var method = options.method.toUpperCase();
```

I was not setting the `method` property in the `options` and it wasn't erroring saying that it couldn't send, it basically just exited the method without warning...

I changed it to this:

```
var method = (options.method || 'GET').toUpperCase();
```

and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

So you're creating 2 objects with the same prototype, and the data is in the prototype itself. Since the prototype is an object, and it is the same, both resulting objects have the same references for their data objects and functions.

You need to specify the data not in the prototype object, but for each instance instead.

So after you create `var $this = Object.create(this);`, you must add the data to `$this`, such as `successFunc`, otherwise the next call will override this data.

Comment: I originally suspected something like this, but i couldn't recreate the problem in a fiddle.

Comment: you need to do a timeout or something, to let the second instruction run. You'll see that by the time the timeout for the callback is hit, both will at least have the exact same callback function. I'm not sure about the `Promise` thing however, but I'm sure it must be doing the same with the AJAX request, since there's nothing else wrong with the code.

Comment: I had a timeout of 100ms in my mocked `// ajax stuff`, i get both alerts, one with a 1, the second with a 2 (set by the callbacks passed to .success) https://jsfiddle.net/swqndc09/ What am i doing differently?

Comment: @KevinB I have added `// ajax stuff` for reference

Comment: @KevinB That's unexpected. My answer might not be correct then. It seems to be working just fine.

Comment: see, $this is returned from http.request, and then .success is called from that, so `this` inside of .success will be the same as $this, which is why it works rather than failing there. each request is getting it's own object.

Comment: I changed it to make an instance of `http` instead... that didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

The `sucess`and `error` variable used to store your callback functions must be created within your `request` function to be truly unique per request. However, if you're going to use Promises, I'd suggest simplifying the whole deal using `load` and `error` event listeners available to the `XMLHttpRequest` object (a nice example can be found on MDN's [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) article) and simply passing in your success and failure functions the `then` method of your Promise instance.

Here's a simplified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dst87310/1/) example using a timeout to simulate a 500 millisecond HTTP request.